# hibernate-annotations with hibernate-core 5

Tags: hibernate

Why hibernate-annotations are not supported? Are they required with hibernate-core 5 or they were replaced?

I'm using hibernate-core 5 and hibernate-annotations 3 and there are ClassNotFound exceptions.

Comment: Some source code examples would be very useful. Hibernate 3.5 onwards supports annotations, as detailed in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar` you should to use `hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar`